# Starting out in Python Development: Coin-Tossing Loops

Tags: python, coin-flipping

Afternoon all,

I cross your paths as someone looking to teachimself programming.  As such, I've started with Python.  As a disclaimer, I have searched the question for some examples of Python coin-tosses but I've not really understood any of the code that previous askers have come up with.

**My task**
My educationanal material has asked me to come up with an application that flips the virtual coin 100 times and then prints the results.  My ideas was to use an infinite loop, break out when the coin toss reaches 100 and then print the results.

I've not quite achieved this and I'm not spotting the error in what I've written.  It seems to achieve the 100 flips but then only prints out 50 of either Heads / Tails; thus my error is somewhere in the counting logic?

Any explanation (bearing in mind I'm a beginner, not a moron!) would get both my gratitude and my upvote

Thanks for reading

```
# Exercise 3.2
# Heads and Tails coin flip

#import random
import random

#declare variables
heads = 0
tails = 0
cointoss = 0
coinresult = random.randint(1,2)

#start the loop
while True:
    cointoss +=1

    #end the loop if cointoss is greater than 100
    if cointoss > 100:
        break
    if coinresult == 1:
        heads +=1
        cointoss +=1
    elif coinresult == 2:
        tails +=1
        cointoss +=1

  print("Heads came up", heads, "times")
  print("Tails came up", tails, "times")
```

Comment: your indentation needs to be fixed.

Comment: A loop with a fixes number of iterations is written `for i in xrange(100):` -- no need for `break`.

Comment: @ Paul: The indenting only looks broken due to how I've had to use it within the forum software.  It seems to run fine in IDLE.

Comment: I edited your indent to help avoid reader confusion.

Comment: Since there are only two possible results you can use `else:` instead of `elif coinresult == 2`.

Comment: Simplest would be `heads = sum(random.randint(0,1) for _ in range(tosses))`  and then `tails = tosses - heads`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this line:

```
coinresult = random.randint(1,2)
```

inside the while loop. Otherwise you get value once, and just use it over and over inside the loop and you were adding to cointoss in two places per loop.

Comment: Although this is right, it doesn't answer his original question.

Answer (score 4):

You're incrementing `cointoss` twice per loop.

```
while True:
    cointoss +=1      # You already incremented here, therefore...
    if cointoss > 100:
        break
    if coinresult == 1:
        heads +=1
        cointoss +=1  # ...get rid of this...
    elif coinresult == 2:
        tails +=1
        cointoss +=1  # ...and this.
```

Also, as was pointed out, you should be getting a new `coinresult` somewhere inside the loop.

Comment: Ahh, yes.  Good spot; many thanks.  Upvote and I'm off to try this.

Comment: Ok, this helps me count 100 times, but it's still returning only 100 of either Heads or Tails.  You've got me one step closer!

Comment: @Steven D Andrews I think you just need to integrate [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15141927/1961486) noted above.

Answer (score 3):

You might have an easier time writing your loop by using the [range](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) method, like this:

```
for i in range(0, 100):
    coinresult = random.randint(1, 2)
    if coinresult == 1:
        heads += 1
    else:
        tails += 1
print("Heads came up", heads, "times")
print("Tails came up", tails, "times")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Exercise 3.2
# Heads and Tails coin flip

#import random
import random

#declare variables
heads = 0
tails = 0
cointoss = 0
coinresult = random.randint(1,2)

#start the loop
while True:
   cointoss +=1

#end the loop if cointoss is greater than 100
   if cointoss > 100:
       break
   if coinresult == 1:
       heads +=1
   elif coinresult == 2:
       tails +=1
   coinresult = random.randint(1,2)

print("Heads came up", heads, "times")
print("Tails came up", tails, "times")
```

You never recalled your randomization, therefore the number never changed, and you were adding to cointoss in two places per loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be adventurous, look into [generator expressions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) and the built-in [sum](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) along with random.randint

```
heads = sum(random.randint(0,1) for _ in range(100))
print("Heads came up {} times".format(heads))
print("Tails came up {} times".format(100 - heads))
```

Comment: Ah beat me to it.  This one kind of misses the essence though.  You don't really know what the flips are until after all the flips.  It kind of takes the fun out of the ol' coin toss!

Comment: Appreciate this; but I'll save this one for later.  I'd like to get my head around this one first.